# problems with sending mail

Tags: php, sendmail

I use local server, and there are some problems with sending mail!

I think i must change something in my `php.ini` file. can somebody help me?

The whole problem in this!!! It doesn't return any error! That is why,I'm not able to understand where i wrong?.

Comment: some code would be helpful, maybe ?

Answer (score 2):

Vague question, vague answer: Use [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org).

You can find the description of the ini parameters directly influencing php's mail() function at http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

The problems sending mail fom PHP can be various and many.  Maybe you could try to give us a better description of how sending mail fails (e.g. do you get an error response from calling the mail function within php; is mail not delivered; are you even running a local mailserver or some equivalent library that enables sending off email from the machine). Then, it's easier to solve a potential problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Check if sendmail can actually send emails from your local server

if not probably it is a problem of firewall.

if sendmail works, then the problems is with php, but in my experience the problem is always with the server.